# Order of BizTalk 2006 SP1 Install

Tags: biztalk

I'm installing BizTalk 2006 R2 and will create a new BizTalk group.  Does it matter if I install SP1 before or after creating the new group?  If I install it before creating the group, I assume the databases that get created will be at SP1 level?

-Krip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move quickly on this so installed SP1 before configuring and creating the new group.  It all worked without error so hopefully we're cooking on gas.

-Krip

Answer (score 1):

It should not matter.

Take for example a site that went into production before SP1 was available, they have created groups amongst other things. Then SP1 is released and they must install it.

As a side note, on allmost all the Biztalk projects I have worked on, it is the devs that have installed Biztalk.

Answer (score 0):

The safest bet will be to install BizTalk 2006 R2 first, configure the group completely, make it work and then apply the SP1.

Service pack's are normally installed after the product installation. My gut feeling is you won't be able able to install SP1 in the first place without installing BizTalk 2006 R2